# Where/how to create a background function/thread in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to run a function in the background of an Ember App. I am also using Ember Data. Does Ember.js have a particular way to create a background function/thread?

Say I have a function with a `while(true)` that runs forever doing the things I would like it to do. Where should I put that function in an Ember App?

Update: Here are some ways (if clickable, you can to see an example in jsbin):

- Use `Ember.run.schedule` on `Ember.run.later`. See [this post](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/) and [the api](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html).
- [Using a simple setInterval() in ApplicationRoute](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/462/edit). The UI seems to be running smoothly.
- Use setInterval() inside a Web Worker.

How is `Ember.run.schedule` or `later` better than setInterval?

Comment: As far as I know, JavaScript is single threaded. Ember would not have any control over how the browser creates/processes threads. That is based on a per browser implementation.

Comment: Javascript in browsers run in single thread, even setTimeout, setInterval, ajax etc, run in the same thread. Give a look in that article of John resig for more information http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/. The only way to run things in other threads is using web workers http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp, but this just work in modern browsers.

Comment: @Márcio Rodrigues Correa Júnior, thanks. Where would I put setTimeout in an Ember app?

Comment: I think in any place. But instead of use `setTimeout`. You need to use `Ember.run.later` see the docs http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later